# spresense dnnrt.begin()で戻り値が-16となる

Tags: spresense

spresenseにて、下記のDNNRTサンプルプログラムを実行した際に、dnnrt.begin()で戻り値が-16となるエラーが発生します。
ブートローダの[再インストール](https://developer.sony.com/spresense/development-guides/arduino_set_up_ja.html#_spresense_%E3%83%96%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB)を行なっても改善されません(spresense reference board 3.1.0)。どうしたら良いでしょうか。

```c
#include <Camera.h>
//#include "Adafruit_ILI9341.h"
#include <DNNRT.h>
#include <SDHCI.h>
#define TFT_DC  9
#define TFT_CS  10
//Adafruit_ILI9341 display = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS, TFT_DC);

#define OFFSET_X  (104)
#define OFFSET_Y  (0)
#define CLIP_WIDTH (112)
#define CLIP_HEIGHT (224)
#define DNN_WIDTH  (28)
#define DNN_HEIGHT  (28)

SDClass SD;
DNNRT dnnrt;

DNNVariable input(DNN_WIDTH*DNN_HEIGHT);
const char label[11] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',' '};

void CamCB(CamImage img) {

  if (!img.isAvailable()) return;

  // カメラ画像の切り抜きと縮小
  CamImage small;
  CamErr err = img.clipAndResizeImageByHW(small
                     , OFFSET_X, OFFSET_Y
                     , OFFSET_X + CLIP_WIDTH -1
                     , OFFSET_Y + CLIP_HEIGHT -1
                     , DNN_WIDTH, DNN_HEIGHT);
                     
  if (!small.isAvailable()) return;

  // 認識用モノクロ画像をDNNVariableに設定
  uint16_t* imgbuf = (uint16_t*)small.getImgBuff();
  float *dnnbuf = input.data();
  for (int n = 0; n < DNN_HEIGHT*DNN_WIDTH; ++n) {
    // YUV422の輝度成分をモノクロ画像として利用
    // 学習済モデルの入力に合わせ0.0-1.0に正規化    
    dnnbuf[n] = (float)(((imgbuf[n] & 0xf000) >> 8) 
                      | ((imgbuf[n] & 0x00f0) >> 4))/255.;
  }
  // 推論の実行
  dnnrt.inputVariable(input, 0);
  dnnrt.forward();
  DNNVariable output = dnnrt.outputVariable(0);
  int index = output.maxIndex();
  
 // 推論結果の表示
  String gStrResult;
  if (index < 11) {
    gStrResult = String(label[index]) 
        + String(":") + String(output[index]);
  } else {
    gStrResult = String("Error");    
  }
  Serial.println(gStrResult);

  img.convertPixFormat(CAM_IMAGE_PIX_FMT_RGB565);
  // display.drawRGBBitmap(0, 0, 
  //     (uint16_t *)img.getImgBuff(), 320, 240);
}

void setup() {   
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // SDカードの挿入待ち
  while (!SD.begin()) {Serial.println("Insert SD card");}
  // SDカードにある学習済モデルの読み込み
  File nnbfile = SD.open("model.nnb");
  // 学習済モデルでDNNRTを開始
  int ret = dnnrt.begin(nnbfile);
  if (ret < 0) {
    Serial.println("Runtime initialization failure.");
    if (ret == -16) {
      Serial.print("Please install bootloader!");
      Serial.println(" or consider memory configuration!");
    } else {
      Serial.println(ret);
    }
    return;
  }

  // display.begin();
  // display.setRotation(3);
  // theCamera.begin();
  theCamera.startStreaming(true, CamCB);
}

void loop() { }
```

追記)Arduino IDEを消して再インストールしたら改善されました．原因をご教示いただきたいです．

Answer (score 0):

あまり情報がないので憶測に過ぎませんが、古いDNNRTライブラリが残っていたのではないでしょうか？

本体のブートローダーのバージョンとSpresense Arduino Library のバージョンの不一致でエラーが出たように思います。DNNRTではないですが、私もバージョン不一致でうまく動かないということが昔よくありました。今はもう慣れて、そういうことはありませんが。

あまり回答になってなくて恐縮ですが、考えられる原因としてはそれくらいでしょうか。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます．どうやらArduino IDEのツールからMemoryを1536KBに設定すると-16のエラーが発生します．1536KBより小さく設置した場合には”no enough memory to create variable buffer"というエラーが発生します．高さ120幅160の大きさの画像はspresenseで画像認識を行うには大きすぎますでしょうか．

Comment: ニューラルネットワークの構成によると思います。恐らくConvolutionを多用しており、かつ Outmapの 数も多いのではないでしょうか。Convolution で Outmap 数を増やせば、それだけ必要とするメモリも増えます。ただ多くの場合、対象とするデータに対して、あまり機能していない Convolution や Outmap があるので省くことが可能だと思います。ニューラルネットワークの構成を今一度見直してみるのがよいと思います。